# Replacing _x with string.empty using Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string "region_2>0" where I want to replace _2 with string.empty using Regex.

My expression is `((_)[^_]*)\w(?=[\s=!><])` which in both Regulator and Expresso gives me _2. However, the code(c#):

```
Regex.Match(legacyExpression, "((_)[^_]*)\\w(?=[\\s=!><])").Value
```

gives me "_2>0", which also causes the replace to be wrong (It returns "region" since removing the whole "_2>0" instead of "_2". The result I want is "region>0". Shouldn't the code and the regex programs give the same results? And how can I get it to work?

(Note the string is not static, it could be in many different forms, but the rule is I want to replace the last _X in the string with string.empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the string always region_x<x. where "x" changes but the string is basically the same?

Comment: Shiv Kumar: no, region is not the same either. It could be nnn_nnn_5!=0, nnn_10b=1 or nnn_a>0 for example. So basically i just need to get the last _x of any string, but stopping at the operators (!=<>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code as is into the new project:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var legacyExpression = "region_2>0";
    var rex = Regex.Match(legacyExpression, "((_)[^_]*)\\w(?=[\\s=!><])").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(rex);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The output is `_2`.

Comment: I copied your code, and noticed that my expression actually got a space after it, causing it not to work. At least now I have something to work on in Expresso. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work

```
(_\d+)
```